# ACF and sidebar(WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use ACF-plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

There is a simple HTML file called sidebar.php.
This sidebar.php file has a place to display the image via ACF:

```html
<figure class="Sidebar_Block">
<img class="ACF_Img"  src=" <?php the_field('sidebar-latest') ?> ">  // ****** place to display a picture ****** 
</figure>
```

In other files **(home.php, category.php)** i call **sidebar.php** via command

> get_sidebar();

Image display only works on the home page **(home.php)**
And in the **category.php** file, displaying the image through ACF does not work.

The question is:
**How to connect ACF to category.php and display image via WordPress admin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you saved `sidebar-latest` field only for your home page. I mean, it's attached to the home page. When you call `the_field` and you don't pass the page/post ID in the second argument, it will take the current one.

So for the homepage works because the sidebar image is saved for the home_page but not when you change page, in order to make it work, pass the home page's post ID to the second parameter:

```
<img class="ACF_Img"  src="<?php the_field('sidebar-latest', $home_page_id); ?>">
```

So it will work on all page, also, remember to remove any extra space like my example.